# Python - Code snippet not working on Python 2.5.6, using IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle, python-2.5, self-modifying

I am using a piece of self-modifying code for a college project.

Here it is:

```
import datetime
import inspect
import re
import sys

def main():
    # print the time it is last run
    lastrun = 'Mon Jun  8 16:31:27 2009'

    print "This program was last run at ",
    print lastrun

    # read in the source code of itself
    srcfile = inspect.getsourcefile(sys.modules[__name__])
    f = open(srcfile, 'r')
    src = f.read()
    f.close()

    # modify the embedded timestamp
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.ctime(datetime.datetime.now())
    match = re.search("lastrun = '(.*)'", src)
    if match:
        src = src[:match.start(1)] + timestamp + src[match.end(1):]

    # write the source code back
    f = open(srcfile, 'w')
    f.write(src)
    f.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Error returned:

```
# This is the script's output
This program is last run at  Mon Jun  8 16:31:27 2009
# This is the error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rui Gomes\Desktop\teste.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Rui Gomes\Desktop\teste.py", line 13, in main
    srcfile = inspect.getsourcefile(sys.modules[__name__])
  File "C:\Python31\lib\inspect.py", line 439, in getsourcefile
    filename = getfile(object)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\inspect.py", line 401, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in module'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__main__' (built-in)> is a built-in module
```

I'd be thankful for any solutions.

Comment: Self-modifying code is evil. In any language.

Comment: Check your path, you're calling \Python31\lib resources from IDLE 2.5.6?

Comment: Wow that's a bad idea.  Why can't the run-time be recorded somewhere else?

Comment: It's just proof of concept. Academic curiosity.

Comment: And it was hard to debug.  What more proof do you need that it's a bad idea?

Comment: I understand it's a bad idea, and I'd never do it on a "real" project, but I was curious to see if I could get this working properly.

Comment: @Fancisco P.: This is a common use case.  Very common.  And no one uses self-modifying code to do this.  They use files.  Often in the /var/log or /var/run directories.  "Curiosity" should -- perhaps -- have limits defined by practicality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It runs perfectly when run outside of IDLE -- so therefore the problem is not in your code alone, but in the environment where you are executing it.  When you run the erroring portion of your code in IDLE you get this output:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> sys.modules[__name__]
<module '__main__' from 'C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw'>
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(sys.modules[__name__])
'C:\\Python26\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw'
```

When you run this **in** IDLE

```
# read in the source code of itself
srcfile = inspect.getsourcefile(sys.modules[__name__])
f = open(srcfile, 'r')
src = f.read()
f.close()
```

you are actually trying to modify `'C:\\Python26\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw'` ... which IDLE will not let you do.

The long and the short of it seems to be that what you have written **does** work: but it cannot be run in IDLE.

Comment: The problem is not related with the openfile part because the exception is triggered in inspect.getsourcefile(sys.modules[__name__])

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `__file__` global attribute to get the current module's source path.

From the 2.6 docs:

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if
>   it was loaded from a file. The
>   `__file__` attribute is not present for C modules that are statically linked
>   into the interpreter; for extension
>   modules loaded dynamically from a
>   shared library, it is the pathname of
>   the shared library file.

EDIT:

I made the assumption that inspect.getsourcefile() would always throw TypeError when inspecting the `__main__` module.  That's only the case when run from an interactive interpreter.  I stand corrected. Derp.